# I'm working with pyannote.audio in a Jupyter notebook, I get ValueError: No loader for files with '.rttm' suffix

Tags: python, pytorch, speech-recognition, python-3.10, pytorch-lightning

I'm working on a speaker diarization pipeline using `pyannote-audio`.

I have trained the model and loaded the checkpoints, running python scripts in Jupyter notebooks.

However I encounter an issue when running the code in the Jupyter cells:

```
from pyannote.database import registry
from pyannote.database import loader
from pyannote.audio import Inference
from pyannote.audio.pipelines import SpeakerDiarization as SpeakerDiarizationPipeline
metric = DiarizationErrorRate()
registry.load_database("pyannote/full_database.yml")
ami = registry.get_protocol('PROJECT.SpeakerDiarization.complete')
pipeline = SpeakerDiarizationPipeline(segmentation= segmentation_model, embedding=embedding_model)
for file in ami.test():
    # apply finetuned pipeline
    print("Expected output")
    print(file["annotation"])
    expected_output = file["annotation"].get_timeline()
    file["finetuned pipeline"] = pipeline(file)
    print("Calculating final output........ ")
    print(file["finetuned pipeline"] )
    diar , centroid = pipeline.apply(file, return_embeddings=True)
```

The error occurs when I try to run in a cell,

```
for file in ami.test():
```

I get

```
    99     if path.suffix not in LOADERS:
    100         msg = f"No loader for files with '{path.suffix}' suffix"
--> 101         raise ValueError(msg)
    102 
    103     Loader = LOADERS[path.suffix].load()

ValueError: No loader for files with '.rttm' suffix .
```

The definitions of the databases, protocols etc are all correct.

There is no error in the code since when I run it from a Python script,  there are no errors at runtime.

I tried uninstalling the `pyannote.database` package and cloning the `pyannote.database` develop tree, but still I get the same error.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-database.git@develop
```

I checked the files. There is an `RTTMLoader` class in the `loader.py` of `pyannote.database`.

Seems like the issue is with `RTTMLoader` not getting recognised in the entry points of the `LOADERS` in `custom.py` of `pyannote.database`:

```
LOADERS = {
    ep.name: ep
    for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group="pyannote.database.loader")
}
```

I need to run the code in a notebook in order to continue working on my project.